# Issue adding second variable to scatter plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, filter, geom-point

Been set this question for an assignment - but i've never used R before - any help is appreciated.
Many thanks.
Question:
Produce a scatter plot to compare CO2 emissions from Brazil and Argentina between 1950 and 2019....
I can get it for Brazil but cannot figure out how to add Argentina.
I think i have to do something with geom_point and filter?

```
df%>%
  filter(Country=="Brazil", Year<=2019 & Year>=1950) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = CO2_annual_tonnes)) + 
    geom_point(na.rm =TRUE, shape=20, size=2, colour="green") + 
    labs(x = "Year", y = "CO2Emmissions (tonnes)")
```

Comment: I'd recommend going through some beginner tutorials on ggplot to see how it works, since this is more or less a question of just how to use ggplot. The official docs are very thorough and link to several more tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on what you're looking to do, but generally adding another dimension to a scatter plot where you already have clear `x` and `y` dimensions is done by applying an aesthetic (color, shape, etc) or via faceting.

In both approaches, you actually *don't* want to filter the data.  You use either aesthetics or faceting to "filter" in a way and map the data appropriately based on the `country` column in the dataset.  If your dataset contains more countries than Argentina and Brazil, you will want to filter to only include those, so:

```
your_filtered_df <- your_df %>%
    dplyr::filter(Country %in% c("Argentina", "Brazil"))
```

#### Faceting

Faceting is another way of saying you want to split up your one plot into two separate plots (one for Argentina, one for Brazil).  Each plot will have the same aesthetics (look the same), but will have the appropriate "filtered" dataset.

In your case, you can try:

```
your_filtered_df %>%
ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = CO2_annual_tonnes)) +
    geom_point(na.rm =TRUE, shape=20, size=2, colour="green") +
    facet_wrap(~Country)
```

#### Aesthetics

Here, you have a lot of options.  The idea is that you tell `ggplot2` to map the *appearance of individual points in the point geom* to the value specified in `your_filtered_df$Country`.  You do this by placing one of the aesthetic arguments for `geom_point()` inside of `aes()`.  If you use `shape=`, for example it might look like this:

```
your_filtered_df %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = CO2_annual_tonnes)) +
        geom_point(aes(shape=Country), na.rm =TRUE, size=2, colour="green")
```

This should show a plot that has a legend created to and two different shapes for the points that correspond to the country name.  It's **very important** to remember that when you put an aesthetic like `shape` or `color` or `size` inside of `aes()`, you **must not also have it outside**.  So, this will behave correctly:

```
geom_point(aes(colour=Country), ...)
```

But this will not:

```
geom_point(aes(colour=Country), colour="green", ...)
```

When one aesthetic is outside, it overrides the one in `aes()`.  The second one will still show all points as green.

#### Don't Do this... but it works

OP posted a comment that indicated some additional hints from the professor, which was:

> We were given the hint in the question "you can embed piped filter
> functions within geom_point objects"

I believe they are referring to a final... very bad way of generating the points.  This method would require you to have *two* `geom_point()` objects, and send each one a different filtered dataset.  You can do this by accessing the `data=` argument within each `geom_point()` object.  There are many problems with this approach, including the lack of a legend being generated, but if you simply *must* do it this way... here it is:

```
# painful to write this.  it goes against all good practices with ggplot
your_filtered_df %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = CO2_annual_tonnes)) +
    geom_point(data=your_filtered_df %>% dplyr::filter(Country=="Argentina"),
        color="green", shape=20) +
    geom_point(data=your_filtered_df %>% dplyr::filter(Country=="Brazil"),
        color="red", shape=20)
```

You should probably see why this is not a good convention.  Think about what you would do for representing 50 different countries... the above codes or methods would work, but with this method, you would have 50 individual `geom_point()` objects in your plot... ugh.  Don't make a typo!

Comment: Fab thanks - will try this now.  We were given the hint in the question "you can embed piped filter functions within geom_point objects" if that is any use in what the teacher wants us to do.

Comment: Oh no... they don't want you to use two `geom_point()` objects do you?  The horrible bad bad way to do this is to supply a different filtered dataframe for two `geom_point()` object via `data=`.  I'll post an edit to give you the horrible no-no way...

Comment: Great so this has worked - giving me this `df%>%
   dplyr::filter(Country %in% c("Argentina", "Brazil")) %>%
  filter(Year<=2019 & Year>=1950) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = CO2_annual_tonnes)) + geom_point(na.rm =TRUE, shape=20, size=2, colour="green") + labs (x = "Year", y = "CO2Emmissions (tonnes)")`

Comment: Thanks - I'll bear in mind this is not the right way for future!