# Colour line on scatter plot - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, scatter-plot

I have created a scatter plot for CO2 emissions for Argentina and Brazil. How would i make them different colours? at the moment it's all green.
Thanks
Lois

```
df%>%
  dplyr:: filter(Country %in% c("Argentina", "Brazil")) %>%   
  filter(Year<=2019 & Year>=1950) %>%   
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = CO2_annual_tonnes)) + 
    geom_point(na.rm =TRUE, shape=20, size=2, colour="green") + 
    labs (x = "Year", y = "CO2Emmissions (tonnes)")
```

Comment: OP, you seem to be asking a lot here today on this question... what type of reference material or instruction was provided in your class?  [The answer I provided you here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69772304/9664796) on your previous question should get you there.  You need to put color into the `aes()` function.  It can either go inside `ggplot(aes(...), ...)` or `geom_point(aes(...),...)`.  Map color to `Country` and you should be all good.  If you need to specify colors, do that with a `scale_color_*` function - just chck that documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df%>% 
  dplyr:: filter(Country %in% c("Argentina", "Brazil")) %>%    
  filter(Year<=2019 & Year>=1950) %>%    
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = CO2_annual_tonnes, colour=factor(country))) + 
  geom_point(na.rm =TRUE, shape=20, size=2) + 
  labs (x = "Year", y = "CO2Emmissions (tonnes)")
```

Comment: Thank you TarJae - yes I know I'm asking a lot - this the the very last step of the assignment. The only information we were given was for a single plot and not how to colour 2 plots independantly. I will give it another go. Thanks for your help

Comment: @LoisFleming. If this is an exercise than be careful. The trick is if you use `fill` in this case it won't work because of shape=20. If you use shape=21 then fill will work. Just  a nostice. And please consider to upvote and accept if the answer solved your problem!

Comment: Ok - they're different colours now :) - i think i've done it technically the "wrong" way as you have mentioned with the geom_point but if it's what they want there we go. Thanks for showing m the right way as well for future. I only saw my first line of code ever on tuesday and have really struggled with it so thanks again.